# Pass in a certain entry within an array of structs into a function

Tags: c++, function, struct

My struct looks like:

```
struct Student
{
    string sStudentFName;
    string sStudentLName;
    int iTestScore;
    char cGrade;
};
```

I then created an array called Students that holds 20 Student structs

```
Student Students[20] = {};
```

I then created this function to print out the information of each student:

```
void PrintStudentInfo(Student students[], const int iSize)
{
    /// Get the longest student name (first and last).
    static size_t iLongestFullName = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
    {
        string sFullName = students[i].sStudentFName + ", " + students[i].sStudentLName;
        if (iLongestFullName < sFullName.length())
            iLongestFullName = sFullName.length();
    }

    /// Print the scores....
    for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
    {
        string sFullName = students[i].sStudentFName + ", " + students[i].sStudentLName;
        cout << left << setfill('.') << setw(16);
        cout << sFullName;
        cout << students[i].iTestScore;
        cout << right << setfill('.') << setw(8);
        cout << students[i].cGrade;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I want to create a function that will print out the information of each student but only if they fall within a certain range between iMinScore and iMaxScore.

```
void PrintStudentInfoRange(const int iMinScore, const int iMaxScore, Student students[], const int iSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++) {
        if (students[i].iTestScore >= iMinScore && students[i].iTestScore <= iMaxScore) {
            // issue occurs here \/
            PrintStudentInfo(students[i], iSize);
        }
    }
}
```

I call the **PrintStudentInfoRange** function by:

```
PrintStudentInfoRange(90, 100, Students, STUDENTS);
```

This line will print out the information of each student that fall within 90 and 100.

I cannot figure out the syntax of passing in a particular entry from the students array into the **PrintStudentInfo** function. I have to call the **PrintStudentInfo** function within **PrintStudentInfoRange**
The error I am getting is *no suitable conversion function from "Student" to "Student *" exists*.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: `PrintStudentInfo` takes in a list of Students[], and so passing in one (e.g. `Student`) isn't possible unless it's an array with one student in it.

Comment: Write a new `PrintOneStudentInfo(..)` function that takes a single student and prints that students info out.... (you could then refactor your `PrintStudentInfo` function to iterate over your array calling `PrintOneStudentInfo(..)` for each student). One function builds on another....

Comment: @alexyorke Since they are using raw arrays / pointers they technically can use it print just one `Student`. I would however also say that there should be a function printing a single student.

Comment: That would be a good idea. Unfortunately, the assignment only tells me to modify what is inside PrintStudentInfoRange and I cannot make any new functions.

Comment: Thank you for the help alexyorke and David C. Rankin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PrintStudentInfo` expects a pointer to `Student` and the number of `Student`s to print starting from that pointer.

So what you can do is pass in the correct pointer to the first student and then size `1`:

```
PrintStudentInfo(&students[i], 1);
```

From a code quality perspective, I would however encourage you to write a function printing only one student, which is then called by `PrintStudentInfo` in a loop to print all students and which can be reused by `PrintStudentInfoRange`.

I would also advice not to use raw arrays at all, because they do not behave intuitively. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I attempted to pass in the pointer to the first student but I got this error: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)`
So I figured that was not the solution.

Comment: Oh wait my apologizes. It worked. I typed 20 instead of 1. I understand why that error occured.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping all students both in PrintStudentInfo() as well as  PrintStudentInfoRange(). Sent a single student for printing like so. In the next level, attempt using std::vector in place of array:

```
void PrintStudentInfo(Student* pstudents)
{
        string sFullName = pstudents->sStudentFName + ", " + pstudents->sStudentLName;
        cout << left << setfill('.') << setw(16);
        cout << sFullName;
        cout << pstudents->iTestScore;
        cout << right << setfill('.') << setw(8);
        cout << pstudents->cGrade;
        cout << endl;
}


void PrintStudentInfoRange(const int iMinScore, const int iMaxScore, Student students[], const int iSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++) {
        if (students[i].iTestScore >= iMinScore && students[i].iTestScore <= iMaxScore) {
            PrintStudentInfo(&students[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and alternative solution.